# How to give fixed text in the form field in angular?

Tags: angular

I have two fields.One is Id and another one is URL.My question was how to give fixed text in the fields.
In the below code,in the URL field the user has to give the IP address and port number.In that field,there should be fixed text **https:\**.The user's data should enter after this **https:\**.while storing in database,the data should like **https:\192.145.23.45\7894**.

please answer this question.

Thanks in advance:)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>url</mat-label>
   <input matInput placeholder="Url"formControlName="url" >
   <mat-error *ngIf="appawareform.controls.url.invalid  && 
    appawareform.controls.url.touched && 
    !appawareform.controls.url.value">url is required</mat-error>
   <mat-hint align="start">NOTE:server:portno</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add static text inside an input form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369197/how-to-add-static-text-inside-an-input-form)

Comment: You can add `<span matPrefix>https://</span>` in mat-form-field to display it. To store it, just patch the value before sending to the server

Comment: I am using the appearence **outline**.so it overlaps.Is anyother way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding a simple function on the input field.

> (focusin)="addPrefix($event)"

Please see the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqgf1v-5c2npx).

Comment: Actually,I used this too.But the problem is for the first time it shows but when again clicks that means it doesn't show.

Comment: I have modified above demo, Added ngModel so it will display the value if you click again. Please check now.

Comment: It is working.But can you please explain me why we add ngmodel

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using reactive forms, it is not recommended (and also deprecated) to use `ngModel` with reactive forms. I bring this up, since the other answer uses it.

Instead I would recommend to listen to `valueChanges` of the form, and always append the `https://` to the formcontrol. We can use rxjs `filter` to filter out when value is `https://`

Then you can use a custom validator to check the value (since `Validators.required` does not apply in this case, as control will always have value `https://` no matter what) and either set a custom error or return `null`, which is considered as valid.

So I suggest the following:

```ts
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operator'

ngOnInit() {
  this.appawareform = this.formBuilder.group({
    url: ["https://", this.validateUrl]
  });

  this.appawareform.get("url").valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(value => value !== 'https://')
  ).subscribe(value => {
    this.appawareform
      .get("url")
      // we need to add emitEvent:false to avoid infinite loop
      .patchValue("https://" + value.substring(8), { emitEvent: false });
  });
}

validateUrl(c: FormControl) {
  return c.value === "https://" ? { notValid: true } : null;
}
```

Then in template you check for this error:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="appawareform.hasError('notValid', 'url')>...</mat-error>
```

Then also remember to unsubscribe from `valueChanges` when component is destroyed!

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9k5qp-dc2gcq?file=app/input-overview-example.ts)**

*P.S, this does not check that that what user types is a valid IP and port. You would need to extend the custom validator to check that also. But since that is not the scope of your question, I'm not including that.*

Comment: You are welcome. If either answer was suitable for you, you can consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of answers :)